# glue together a sequence of holomorphic forms

Tags: complex-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, complex-manifolds

hallo,

my problem is the following: i have a finite sequence of holomorphic $k-$forms $\alpha_{k}$, each defined on open subsets $U_{k} \subset M$, where $M$ is a complex $n$-dimensional manifold, such that $\bigcup_{k}U_{k} = M$. is there any method of gluing the holomorphic $k$-forms to give one global holomorphic $k-$form on $M$. Or if this is not possible, is there any possibility of gluing them that weakens the holomorphicity of the globaly defined $k$-form ? maybe meromorphic ? I hope I've presented my question clearly, and hope for a response. Many thanks in advance.

dimitry

Comment: Are you assuming that  $\alpha_k$ and $\alpha_\ell$ agree on $U_k\cap U_\ell$? In this case, certainly yes.

Comment: And in the contrary case, certainly no.

Comment: Yes but if they do not agree on the cuts, is there any possibility to glue them together?

Comment: I'm not sure what "glue together" would mean then. You'd have
to modify them first, but I'm not sure what you allow.

Comment: how to modify them? can you give a short example?

Comment: Just to make an example, take $M=\mathbb{CP}^1=\mathbb{C}\cup\\{\infty\\}$. Take $U_1=\mathbb{C}$ and $U_2=\mathbb{C}^*\cup\\{\infty\\}$, $\alpha_1=e^{z}dz$, $\alpha_2=e^{1/z}dz$. How could you glue them? What conditions of "compatibility" would you like to ask for? I mean, what should the link between the data and the result be, apart from the latter being a holomorphic (or meromorphic) form?

Comment: Maybe you could do that if you allow the global form to have values in some vector bundle. In this case, you have to check if your local values satisfy the cocycle identity (more precisely, if $s_k$ are the local values, you must find some invertible (holomorphic) matrices $g_{kl}$ satisfying $s_k=g_{kl} s_l$ and also the cocycle identities)